# Mac: Terminal (zsh) command not found

Tags: mac, terminal, shell, oh-my-zsh

I'm having a lot of troubles with terminal lately. I must have messed up somewhere, because it used to work just fine and now I can't get it to recognize my commands anymore neither `nvm` or `global npm` packages like `expo`. It just gives me errors like this:

```
▶ expo      
zsh: command not found: expo
```

```
▶ nvm ls
zsh: command not found: nvm
```

(BTW: `npm`, `brew` and `j` commands are found )

If I do `echo $PATH` I get:

```
/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/anaconda/bin:~/Library/Python/2.7/bin:~/.npm-global/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

(strange behavior is that if I do `echo $PATH` again it returns two times the same output in one line)

A readable version of it (replacing `:` with `:\n`

```
/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:
/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk/tools:
/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:
/Applications/anaconda/bin:
~/Library/Python/2.7/bin:
~/.npm-global/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin
```

My `.zshrc` file looks like this:

```
# Node & NPM
#PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
PATH="~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"
#PATH="~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules:$PATH"

# Git
alias master="git checkout master"
alias dev="git checkout develop"
alias hotfix="git flow hotfix"
alias feature="git flow feature"
alias tags="git push --tags"

# Pip - https://gist.github.com/haircut/14705555d58432a5f01f9188006a04ed
PATH="~/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda2 4.4.0 installer
PATH="/Applications/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# Android
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk
PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:$PATH"
PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:$PATH"
PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:$PATH"

alias emu="pushd ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools;emulator -avd Pixel_2; popd"

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/Users/norfeldt/.oh-my-zsh

ZSH_THEME="avit"

# Autojump
[[ -s `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh ]] && . `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh

# shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# Load zsh-autosuggestions.
source /usr/local/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh

# zsh-syntax-highlighting
source /Users/norfeldt/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh

export PATH
```

ANY help would be HIGHLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've this error and resolved it adding this on my `~/.zshrc`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

See more here:

https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/3507#issuecomment-431106509